# I cant get the data that is being entered into the form uploaded to the database

Tags: php, mysql, image-uploading

Im trying to allow a user to register on the site. However when the user enters their details and presses the submit button, the details do not insert into the db table as they should. The image insert however does work, but because the new user details aren't uploaded the image does not match a user. Any help would be greatly appreciated as the work i am doing is to be submitted in less than 48 hours.

This error keeps appearing

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpuRNmad' to '../images/242167777kieran.jpeg' in /var/www/vhosts/kmoreland02.students.cs.qub.ac.uk/httpdocs/deals4students/index.php on line 31

Here is the form code

```
<div id="register">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="title">
                                    <h2 class="wow bounce">Become a Registered User!</h2>
                                    <p class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.6s">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy.</p>
                                </div>
                                <form  action="#" method="post" class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.9s" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
                                    <div class="alert alert-error"></div>   
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                        <input name="newforename" type="text" class="form-control" id="newforename" placeholder="Enter your forename" required>
                                        <input name="newsurname" type="text" class="form-control" id="newsurname" placeholder="Enter your surname" required >
                                        <input name="newemail" type="text" class="form-control" id="newemail" placeholder="Enter your email" required >
                                        <input name="newuniversity" type="text" class="form-control" id="newuniversity" placeholder="Enter your university/college/inst." required>
                                        <input name="newpassword" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required />
                                       <label>Select your Profile Picture: </label> <input  name="uploads[]" type="file" multiple />
                                        <input name="create" type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success" value="Register"/>
                                    </div>


                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
                            </form>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is the code for used to upload the inserted data to the db

```
<?php

include("conn.php");

if(isset($_POST["create"])){


    $getforename = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["newforename"]);
    $getsurname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["newsurname"]);
    $getemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["newemail"]);
    $getuniversity = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["newuniversity"]);
    $getpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["newpassword"]);


    $insertu = "INSERT INTO DealsUsers (id, Forename, Surname, Email, University/College, password) VALUES (NULL,'$getforename','$getsurname','$getemail','$getuniversity','$getpassword')";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $insertu);


    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

    $total = count($_FILES['uploads']['name']);
    if($total >0){
        for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){
        $tmppath = $_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $ran = rand();
        $newfilepath = "../images/".$ran.$_FILES['uploads']['name'][$i];
        $pathname = $ran.$_FILES['uploads']['name'][$i];

        move_uploaded_file($tmppath, $newfilepath);
        $insertpp = "INSERT INTO DealsUserImg(user_id, path)
                    VALUES('$last_id', '$pathname')";

        $resultpp = mysqli_query($conn, $insertpp) or die(mysqli_error($conn));;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is the /images/ folder writeable? Check the permissions of the folder and make sure the sctipt is allowed to write to it. What OS are you on?

Comment: yes i checked that just know and the permissions allow for read write

Comment: Please do not use the > character for personal formatting preferences, it has a special purpose. I had to edit that out.

Comment: im new to this sorry

Answer (score 1):

After a little bit of research this worked for me on a Windows machine:

```
<?php

include("conn.php");

if (isset($_POST["create"])) {
    $getforename = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["newforename"]);
    $getsurname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["newsurname"]);
    $getemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["newemail"]);
    $getuniversity = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["newuniversity"]);
    $getpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["newpassword"]);

    $insertu = "INSERT INTO DealsUsers (`id`, `Forename`, `Surname`, `Email`, `University/College`, `password`) VALUES (NULL,'$getforename','$getsurname','$getemail','$getuniversity','$getpassword')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $insertu) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

    $total = count($_FILES['uploads']['name']);
    if ($total > 0) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
            $tmppath = $_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $ran = rand();
            $newfilepath = "../images/" . $ran . $_FILES['uploads']['name'][$i];
            $pathname = $ran . $_FILES['uploads']['name'][$i];

            move_uploaded_file($tmppath, $newfilepath);

            $insertpp = "INSERT INTO DealsUserImg (`user_id`, `path`) VALUES('$last_id', '$pathname')";
            $resultpp = mysqli_query($conn, $insertpp) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        }
    }
}
```

Your mistake was to not surround the column names in the first statement with backticks and this caused an unhandled error. You can also remove the `id` and the correlating in the MySQL statement. The id is set automatically even if it's not included in the statement.

What you should do next:

1. Check if the user already exists and encrypt (`password_hash()` to hash the password and `password_verify()` to check it against a plain password) the password before you save it into the database.
2. Validate all inputs before saving them to the database. A client-side validation with HTML or JavaScript is not enough!
3. Add a captcha (as like Google ReCaptcha) to protect your script from being spammed with new users.
4. Take a look at PHPs [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).
5. Currently it's possible to upload more than one file without your permission. Remove the brackets from the name of the upload-field and the for-loop in your code which is responsible to save all the files coming in the upload-array. It's only one avatar so there's no need to give a potential spammer the chance to upload as many images as he want to your site.
6. Check if the uploaded file is really an image and within a specific file size. At the moment everyone can upload everything in every size (until upload_max_filesize hits) to your site and even execute it, if he accesses it in the image folder.

Comment: I added the back ticks in the insert query however still no luck. The image uploads fine now with no error but the users details still do not insert into the database

Comment: no nothing appears when im on the site and input the data

Comment: Did you replaced the script with mine or just added the backticks to yours?

Comment: just added the backticks . The db table names in your script don't have capital letters so don't match up to my tables

Comment: Did you tried to add an error control to the `mysqli_query` as you did in the second one? `or die(mysqli_error($conn))`

Comment: i hadn't actually ill try that now

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''id', 'Forename', 'Surname', 'Email', 'University/College', 'password') VALUES (' at line 1

Comment: These are not "backticks" but "single quotes". This a a backtick: `

Comment: Okay so im a complete fool. Thanks a lot i think its all good now. Im gonna test it once more here to be sure

Comment: Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpatQpte' to '../images/392739584owl.jpeg' in /var/www/vhosts/kmoreland02.students.cs.qub.ac.uk/httpdocs/deals4students/index.php on line 30

Comment: okay so everything uploaded to the db. But the image didn't move to the images folder

Comment: The script runs on a linux machine, is that right? Are you sure the permissions of the `../images` folder are set to `755` and the owner of the folder is `www-data:www-data`?

Comment: im using a mac. The pemissions are set to 777. Im not sure what you mean by the owner of the folder is www-data:www-data

Comment: I did what the image in the comments suggested but no difference

Comment: Did you also set the same for the targeting folder (`../images`)?

Comment: yeah i set it for the source folder and the images folder

Comment: im not overly fussed that it isnt moving to the images file. At least now its uploading to the database and i can move on with my work. I now need to allow users to upload deals on the sites and allow them to edit their profiles and deals all for wednesday evening so i think my focus needs to move onto that

Comment: I probably have found the error. The folder `deals4students` in the path `/var/www/vhosts/kmoreland02.students.cs.qub.ac.uk/httpdocs/d‌​eals4students/` contains some characters which PHP can't interpret. Rename the folder to the same name without these characters (just copy it from this comment) and the script should work.

Comment: thats the exact same file name though

Comment: ... this is the same folder name in ANSI instead of UTF-8: `dâ€Œâ€‹â€Œâ€‹eals4students`.

Comment: it didn't help it

Comment: Just rename it to `deals4students` (copy it from here if it helps).

Comment: am i just changing the name of the folder or the project?

Comment: Can you reload the site, submit the form again and paste the thrown error message here again?

Comment: Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpxAsyHZ' to '../images/1464881284owl.jpeg' in /var/www/vhosts/kmoreland02.students.cs.qub.ac.uk/httpdocs/deals4students/index.php on line 30

Comment: i copied what you had and changed it to that though

Comment: Can you copy it again, create a new folder with the copied name on your mac and move the scripts in this folder?

Comment: Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpUKs3JB' to '../images/1065991163owl.jpeg' in /var/www/vhosts/kmoreland02.students.cs.qub.ac.uk/httpdocs/deals4students/index.php on line 30

Comment: Execute this command in your console: https://pastebin.com/1DrUSELg. This renames the folder to the correct name so we have the same base.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

Comment: In your mac terminal. Not in a script or file.